# Horizontal scroll bar not hiding & Background image not 100%

Tags: html, css

I can't get my x-axis scroll bar to hide on this iframe: http://yourhappyeyes.com/order.html

I tried the standard `.div {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}`

but no luck.

Also having trouble getting the background to not repeat and be 100% even without content.

Go here http://yourhappyeyes.com/ and CTRL - (zoom out) and you'll know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `overflow-x: hidden;` to `#container` instead

```
#container { overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `iframe`, `<div id="nav">` has a property `margin-left: 12px;` that is casing this problem.
See here how can you change css inside an iframe if you haven't control on content loading in iframe. [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling attribute specifies whether or not to display scrollbars in an iframe.

```
scrolling="no"
```

Normally, scrollbars appear in an  when the content is larger than the iframe.

```
<iframe src="/default.html" width="700" height="700" scrolling="no">
```

this will hide scroll bar in iframe